# Erro NullPointerException em java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Eu tenho uma classe do tipo `User` que tem como atributo um vetor de `Sensors`, e a classe `Sensors` tem como atributo um vetor de `Data`.
Depois de criar cinco objetos do tipo User e salvar em um arquivo txt, povoei 3 objetos do tipo Sensor de um determinado User e tentei salvar no mesmo arquivo txt, mas fica dando esse erro de `NullPointerException`.

```java
public class test 
{ 
    public static void main ( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {
        Users[] users = new Users[5];
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Documents\\poo.txt");
        int id=0, goal, id2=0, consumo, n=0, i, j, k, novogoal, idedit, iddelete, iduser;
        boolean type, status;
        String name, password, c, name2, description, novoname, novopassword;
        float cost, novocost;

        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            users[i] = new Users(i, "", "", 0, 0);
            for (j=0; j<50; j++)
            {
                users[i].sensors[j] = new Sensors(j, "", "", false);
                for (k=0; k<100; k++)
                {
                    DateTime time = new DateTime("2004-12-13T21:39:45.618-08:00");
                    users[i].sensors[j].data[k] = new Data(false, 0, time);
                }    
            }
        }

        FUsers fusers = new FUsers();
        FSensors fsensors = new FSensors();
        FData fdata = new FData();

        //criar e salvar usuário
        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tipo de usuário: 1 - ADMIN | 0 - COMUM");
            type = Boolean.parseBoolean(c);
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite seu nome");
            password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a senha");
            c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Custo do kWh");
            cost = Float.parseFloat(c);
            goal = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Meta de consumo"));
            users[i] = fusers.createUser(i, name, password, cost, goal, type);
        }
        fusers.saveUser (file, users);
        //*/

        /*criando um sensor*/
        iduser = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Id do user que terá o sensor"));
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Aparelho ligado ao sensor");
            description = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Localização do aparelho");
            c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("O aparelho está ligado?");
            status = Boolean.parseBoolean(c);
            consumo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Consumo do aparelho"));
            users[iduser].sensors[i] = fsensors.createSensor(i, name2, description, status);
        }
        fsensors.saveSensor(file, users); /*erro aqui*/
    }
}
```

```java
public class FSensors {

    public Sensors createSensor(int id, String name, String description, boolean status)
    {
        Users user = new Users();
        user.sensors[id]= new Sensors(id, name, description, status);
        return user.sensors[id];
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param file
     * @param users
     * @param sensor
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void saveSensor(File file, Users[] user) throws IOException
    {
        int i, j;
        String id, status;
        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<50; j++)
            {
                try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)))
                { 
                    id = Integer.toString(user[i].sensors[j].getId()); /*erro aqui*/
                    status = Boolean.toString(user[i].sensors[j].getStatus());
                    bw.write(id);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(user[i].sensors[j].getNome());
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(user[i].sensors[j].getDescription());
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(status);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.close();
                }  
            }
        }
    }
```

```java
public class FUsers {

    public Users createUser(int id, String name, String password, float cost, int goal, boolean type)
    {
        if (type)
        {
            AdminUser admin = new AdminUser();
            admin.setId(id);
            admin.setName(name);
            admin.setPassword(password);
            admin.setCost(cost);
            admin.setGoal(goal);
            admin.setType(type);
            return admin;
        }
        else
        {
            CommonUser common = new CommonUser();
            common.setId(id);
            common.setName(name);
            common.setPassword(password);
            common.setCost(cost);
            common.setGoal(goal);
            common.setType(type);
            return common;
        } 
    }

    public void saveUser (File file, Users[] user) throws IOException
    {
        int i;
        String id, cost, goal, type;
        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            if (i==0)
            {
                try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)))
                {
                    id = Integer.toString(user[i].getId()); 
                    cost = Float.toString(user[i].getCost());
                    goal = Integer.toString(user[i].getGoal());
                    type = Boolean.toString(user[i].getType());
                    bw.write(id);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(user[i].getName());
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(user[i].getPassword());
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(cost);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(goal);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(type);
                    bw.newLine(); 
                    bw.close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)))
                {
                    id = Integer.toString(user[i].getId()); 
                    cost = Float.toString(user[i].getCost());
                    goal = Integer.toString(user[i].getGoal());
                    type = Boolean.toString(user[i].getType());
                    bw.write(id);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(user[i].getName());
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(user[i].getPassword());
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(cost);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(goal);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.write(type);
                    bw.newLine(); 
                    bw.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```java
public Users (int id, String name, String password, float cost, int goal)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.goal = goal;
}
```

```java
public Sensors (int id, String name, String description, boolean status)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.status = status;
}
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, fico grato!

Comment: Esse erro ocorre porque um atributo ou próprio objeto não foi criado, debug o código e verifique a linha que está ocorrendo o erro e onde você pode consertar, não sei exatamente onde ocorre o erro.

Comment: mas o objeto não está sendo criado naqueles 3 for aninhados?

Comment: Você poderia editar a pergunta para colocar o código do método `createUser`? Há algum método chamado `public void saveSensor(File file, Users[] users)` ao invés de `public void saveSensor(File file, Sensors[] sensors)`? O que há na classe `FUsers`?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei createUser e saveUser, que é o que tem em FUsers. Eu também tentei colocar como parâmetro o vetor de Users, mas tá dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: O seu `fsensors.saveSensor(file, users);` não compila, pois afinal `User[]` não é `Sensor[]`. Além disso, o que é que os construtores de `Users` e `Sensors` fazem?

Comment: O que fazem os construtores das subclasses de `Users`?

Comment: Opa, foi engano meu, lá no método saveSensor era pra ter (file, Users[] user), mas já editei. Como tentei de várias formas acabei copiando errado.

Comment: Já editei também com os construtores de Users e Sensors. Não coloquei construtores nas subclasses de Users, estou atribuindo valores aos atributos com set.

Comment: Postei uma resposta, dê uma olhada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse código é suspeito:

```
    public Sensors createSensor(int id, String name, String description, boolean status)
    {
        Users user = new Users();
        user.sensors[id]= new Sensors(id, name, description, status);
        return user.sensors[id];
    }
```

Observe que o objeto `Users` criado não sobrevive a chamada do método. Esse código é equivalente a este outro código:

```
    public Sensors createSensor(int id, String name, String description, boolean status)
    {
        return new Sensors(id, name, description, status);
    }
```

Vamos simplificar o seu método `saveUser` para evitar copiar e colar tanta coisa:

```
    public void saveUser (File file, Users[] user) throws IOException
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, i != 0)))
            {
                String id = Integer.toString(user[i].getId()); 
                String cost = Float.toString(user[i].getCost());
                String goal = Integer.toString(user[i].getGoal());
                String type = Boolean.toString(user[i].getType());
                bw.write(id);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(user[i].getName());
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(user[i].getPassword());
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(cost);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(goal);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(type);
                bw.newLine(); 
                bw.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Vamos fazer o mesmo com o `createUser`:

```
    public Users createUser(int id, String name, String password, float cost, int goal, boolean type)
    {
        Users user = type ? new AdminUser() : new CommonUser();
        user.setId(id);
        user.setName(name);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setCost(cost);
        user.setGoal(goal);
        user.setType(type);
        return user;
    }
```

Outro problema:

```
        try (BufferedWriter bw = ...)
        { 
            // Várias linhas de código...
            bw.close();
        }
```

Você já está usando o *try-with-resources*  para não ter que se preocupar em fechar o `BufferedWriter`, mas mesmo assim você o fecha. Retire esses `bw.close();`.

Finalmente, olha isso daqui, com os comentários que acrescentei:

```
Users[] users = new Users[5]; // Cria um array com 5 users.
// ...
for (i=0; i<5; i++) // Este for preenche o array "users"
{
    users[i] = new Users(i, "", "", 0, 0); // Coloca 5 users no array.
    for (j=0; j<50; j++) // Este for preenche o array "sensors".
    {
        users[i].sensors[j] = new Sensors(j, "", "", false); // Coloca um sensor no array.
        // ...
    }
}

// Chegando aqui, o array está todo preenchido com usuários,
// e cada usuário todo preenchido com sensors.
// MAS SERÁ QUE ISSO SERÁ ASSIM PARA SEMPRE?

for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    // ...

    // Surpresa! Sobrescreve um user que estava no array com um outro
    // que tem todos os sensors definidos como null!
    users[i] = fusers.createUser(i, name, password, cost, goal, type);
}

// Chegando aqui, o array foi todo sobreescrito com novos usuários,
// e todos estes novos usuários têm um array cheio de nulls como sensors!

// ...

iduser = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Id do user que terá o sensor")); // Escolhe apenas um usuário.
for (i=0; i<3; i++) // Preenche 3 sensors no array de 50 sensors apenas deste usuário.
{
    // ...
    users[iduser].sensors[i] = fsensors.createSensor(i, name2, description, status);
}

// Agora, apenas um usuário têm um array com 3 sensores preenchidos e 47 nulls!
// Os demais, têm 50 nulls!

fsensors.saveSensor(file, users); /*erro aqui*/
```

E então:

```
    public void saveSensor(File file, Users[] user) throws IOException
    {
        int i, j;
        String id, status;
        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            // Um user tem 3 sensors e 47 nulls!
            // Todos os outros têm 50 sensors nulls!
            for (j=0; j<50; j++)
            {
                try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)))
                {
                    // A maioria dos elementos do array é null.
                    // Ao chamar getId() no null, temos um NullPointerException!
                    id = Integer.toString(user[i].sensors[j].getId());
                    // ...
                }
           }
       }
   }
```

Ou seja, talvez você tenha que trocar o seu `for (i=0; i<3; i++)` por `for (i=0; i<50; i++)`. Ou talvez verificar no `for` se `user[i].sensors[j]` é `null`. Ou não sobreescrever os usuários do array criado inicialmente.

Recomendo utilizar listas ao invés de arrays. Arrays têm tamanhos fixos, o que parece ser algo que apenas está a te atrapalhar, enquanto que listas podem ter um tamanho variável que você raramente terá que se preocupar em saber qual é, além de serem muito mais fáceis de se criar e de se utilizar.

Comment: Entendi o que você quis dizer. Porém, as três primeiras posições do user estão ocupadas. Quando eu entro no for (do método saveSensor) pela primeira vez, não devia dar NullPointerException, porque a posição 0 do vetor está ocupada, certo? Mas está dando NullPointerException.

Comment: @poirot Todos os elementos `user[i]` estão ocoupados? Se sim, para cada um deles, há algum `sensor[j]` nulo?

Comment: Todos estão ocupados, e tem sensor[j] nulo.

Comment: @poirot Editei minha resposta. Basicamente, um dos usuários tem 3 sensores e 47 nulls. Todos os demais usuários têm 50 nulls.

Comment: Ahh, entendi agora o que fiz. Valeu, cara!! Ajudou muito